# validate form with javascript with a validation expression

Tags: javascript

So I have a form and I am trying to validate it to make sure no other characters are submitted  I know theirs a validation expression but I do not know how to apply it.I just want it where if the user puts any invalid character that may interfere then it just return false. I tried but it does not seem to work, also please help me make my code  more efficient if there is any way thank you

```js
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["theForm"]["fname"].value;
    var lastName = document.forms["theForm"]["lname"].value;
    var email = document.forms["theForm"]["femail"].value;
    var subject = document.forms["theForm"]["subject"].value;
    
    if  (name == "") {
    
     window.alert("Missing First Name.");
     name.focus();
     return false;
    }
    
    if (lastName == "") {
        alert("Missing Last Name");
        return false;
    }
    
    if (email == "") {
        alert("Missing Email");
        return false;
    }
    
    if (subject == "") {
        alert("Incomplete Action");
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

```css
  input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
  }

  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #993b3b;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
  }

  .formCont {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 152.5px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="formCont">
      <form name="theForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

      <label for="femail">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="femail" name="Email" placeholder="Your email.."


      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question: Is this a simple attempt at learning JavaScript or are you actually working on a project?
Reason: The code is way too simplistic to actually work in any real environment. Also, in today's JS world, you should be using libraries to do everything. A completely plain vanilla JS and CSS project is a super bad way to go - unless of course, your boss will have it no other way.

Comment: Two simple things to add to my previous comment: You always (or pretty much always) use the === (triple) and not == (double) for equality checks. Also, there's a lot more you need to check in an email.

Comment: im doing a project for my college course, so I guess im learning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so since this is a college project. I'm assuming you have to write vanilla JS (if not [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) is a super better alternative).

A couple of things to start off:

`name === ""`

Is better than `name == ""` Because of JavaScript's type coercion.
Also, HTML now has an `email` input type. So

`<input type="email" id="femail" name="Email" placeholder="Your email..">`

Why do you have `window.alert` in one place and `alert` in other places. Oh goodness. This is becoming a code review :).

Anyway, like I said before, if jQuery is a choice, *please*, *please* do.

Comment: Lol im so stressed out with finals man hahah I just need to finish this form and in done

Answer (score 0):

@peterb mentioned correctly here is an example of using jquery

```js
    function validateForm() {
        var name = $("#fname").val();
        var lastName = $("#lname").val();
        var email = $("#femail").val();
        var subject =$("#subject").val();
        
        if  (name == "" || name ==null || name==undefined) {
        
         alert("Missing First Name.");         
           markerror("#fname")
         return false;
        }
        
        if (lastName == "" || lastName ==null || lastName==undefined) {
            alert("Missing Last Name");            
             markerror("#lname")
            return false;
        }
        
        if (email == ""  || email ==null || email==undefined) {
            alert("Missing Email");
            markerror("#femail")
            return false;
        }
        
        if (subject == "" || subject ==null || subject==undefined) {
            alert("Incomplete Action");             
             markerror("#subject")
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    function markerror(index){
   
            $(index).css("border", "1px solid red");
            $(index).focus();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(index).css("border", "1px solid #ccc");
            }, 4000);
    }
```

```css
      input[type=text], select, textarea {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
        resize: vertical;
      }

      input[type=submit] {
        background-color: #993b3b;
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #B0B0B0;
      }

      .formCont {
        text-align: left;
        margin: 152.5px 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        padding: 20px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <form name="theForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

          <label for="femail">Email</label>
          <input type="text" id="femail" name="Email" placeholder="Your email.."


          <label for="subject">Subject</label>
          <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```